# Recover Machine Key that was not marked as exportable upon creation

Tags: windows, windows-server, private-key, cryptography

We have a machine key that is located in: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` that was probably generated using the command `aspnet_regiis "MyKey" -pc`. The key works fine although we want to export it. The problem is the key wasn't marked as exportable when it was initially created, it should have been created using this `aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKey" -exp` so that we could export it in the future.

When we run `aspnet_regiis.exe -px "MyKey" C:\exported.xml -pri` we get the error: `key not valid for use in specified state` which we understand to mean it wasn't marked as exportable when it was created.

Is there a way we can recover the private key, perhaps there is an application we can write in C# to run on the server?

Comment: Have you granted authority to access the container with Aspnet_regiis.exe with -pa switch? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/yxw286t2(v=vs.100)#exporting-an-rsa-key-container